Chromium browser not opening in Xubuntu
Chromium browser installed in xubuntu 22.04. User tpj-ou73 moved to /opt/home/ from /home/. chromium browser not opening.
Tried changing home file in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/
@{HOMEDIRS}=/home/

to
@{HOMEDIRS}=/home/ /opt/home/

which does not work. Hence, the following solution tried
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*

Restarted snap using
service snapd.apparmor start 

Still didn't open. Tried to locate the problem using journalctl -xe
cannot update snap namespace: cannot expand mount entry (none $HOME/.local/share none x-snapd.kind=ensure-dir,x-snapd.must-exist-dir=$HOME 0 0): cannot use invalid home directory
 snap-update-ns failed with code 1


snap packages run confined, and don't have full access to your file-system; access to /opt I don't believe is allowed (a quick check and I get an error when trying to open a package on my release; alas its not jammy), and its not the /home/ directory that it has access to, but the $USER directory within /home, ie. $HOME

@guiverc Thank you for your reply. You are right. There should be a solution to this. Hope I will get in future.
